# Stack Smashing While Using Fgets

Tags: c, fgets, stack-smash

I am trying to get the data from the binary file in the picture and read it correctly. However, I am not doing in the right way. How can I fix my code?
It is correct to use fgets in this case? What is the correct implementation for this case?

PS: I omitted most of the code due to the rules of the site.

```
/* */

tipoErros
ObterMediaAluno(char *nomeArquivoNotas, char *dreAluno, float *media)
{

  /* */

  FILE *arquivoNotas;
  char buffer[COMPRIMENTO_DRE /* 9 */ + 1];
  unsigned numeroProvas;
  float notas[6];
  char *validacao;





  /* */

  if (!nomeArquivoNotas)
    return argumentoNulo;  /* 1 */





  /* */

  if (*nomeArquivoNotas == EOS)
    return argumentoVazio;  /* 2 */





  /* */

  arquivoNotas = fopen(nomeArquivoNotas, "rb");





  /* */

  if (!arquivoNotas)
  {
    fclose(arquivoNotas);
    return erroAbrindoArquivoBinario;  /* 4 */
  } /* if */





  /* */

  numeroProvas = (unsigned) (fgetc(arquivoNotas) - '0');




  while (fgets(buffer, (COMPRIMENTO_DRE /* 9 */ + 1), arquivoNotas) != NULL)
  {

    printf("\n\n%s\n\n", buffer);

    if (strcmp(buffer,dreAluno) == BEM_SUCEDIDO)
    {
      fgets(buffer, 5, arquivoNotas);
      notas[0] = strtof(buffer, &validacao);
      fgets(buffer, 5, arquivoNotas);
      notas[1] = strtof(buffer, &validacao);
      fgets(buffer, 5, arquivoNotas);
      notas[2] = strtof(buffer, &validacao);
      fgets(buffer, 5, arquivoNotas);
      notas[3] = strtof(buffer, &validacao);
      fgets(buffer, 5, arquivoNotas);
      notas[4] = strtof(buffer, &validacao);
      fgets(buffer, 5, arquivoNotas);
      notas[5] = strtof(buffer, &validacao);
      printf("\n\n%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f\n\n\n", notas[0], notas[1], notas[2], notas[3], notas[4], notas[5]);
    } /* if */
    else
    {
      fgets(buffer, 25, arquivoNotas);
      printf("\n\n%s\n\n", buffer);
    } /* else */  

  } /* while */


  return ok;  /* 0 */
} /* ObterMediaAluno */
```

[image]

```
/* output */



UBUNTU 08 --> ./testeMedia notas_binario 111239451


8.90 6.90 7.40 4.90 0.00 1.00




07.309.703.300.001.500.0



04.400.001.402.800.001.5





*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada)
UBUNTU 08 -->
```

Comment: fgets would allow you to overwrite memory beyound the boundary of the stack, you might be using the wrong tool

Comment: Show how you declare and initialize `buffer`.

Comment: I've updated my code.

Comment: I've found out my error. I was using the variable <buffer> to read an invalid amount of data. I've created another variable and the problem was solved. Thank you, guys.